# Passing data from C# to angular js html

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs, cefsharp

I'm building a application using CefSharp which only shows a webpage. I just want to know how do we pass data from my C# app (using CefSharp) to a html which contain a angularjs controller?

For example, if my data are hardcoded, it will be like below:

MainController.js:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
 $scope.qnumbers = [  // hardcoded data
  {
      counter : 'A',
      number : '3456'
  },
  {
      counter : 'B',
      number : '1234'
  },
  {
      counter : 'C',
      number : '7890'
  },
  {
      counter : 'D',
      number : '1122'
  },
  {
      counter : 'E',
      number : '6677'
  },
  {
      counter : 'F',
      number : '5656'
  },
 ]; 
  }]);
```

Then my html would be something like this:

```
                <div class="reg" ng-repeat="qnumber in qnumbers">
                   div class="u1">{{qnumber.counter}}</div>
                   <div class="u2">{{qnumber.number}}</div>
                </div>
```

What if now my data is not hardcoded but comes from my C# application, how would I have to write in my html? How do we pass the data into the MainController?

Comment: do an ajax get call using `$http.get` method, and get data inside its success function..

Comment: I want the C# app to trigger sending of data, not the html page. So, I don't think I can use $http.get method. I want the C# app to send the data whenever the data is ready. If I use ajax call, I won't know when the data is ready on the C# side.

Comment: you'll need to build rest APIs in C# and call them by angular

Comment: @Coolguy The C# app can only send data when the user requests it. There's no way to force data down the browser's throat. If you want to have a long standing connection to which the server can periodically send data at its own discretion, you need to set up long polling or a websocket endpoint.

Comment: Nope. I can call a js function in the html from the C# application (using EvaluateScriptAsync). That's why the C# app can trigger sending of my data. But I want to know is how to put the data into the MainController?

Comment: Like for example I have a Random(data) function in my html. My C# app can call this function and pass the data into html.

Comment: Show some code here, what you're talking about. Code can better explain it.

Comment: On my C# side, I can write like this:                                                           var script = string.Format("Random(\'{0}\', {1}, \'{2}\');", data1, data2, data3); browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script); "Random" is a function from my html. And on my html side:                                                           Random = function (d1, d2, d3) {                                    $('#reg1').text(d1);
$('#reg2').text(d2);
$('#reg3').text(d3);} So, I can successfully pass my data from C# to html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this documentation [How do you call a Javascript method from .NET?](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#CallJS)

You can do anything you want if you successfully use this. For example, set up a `$scope.$watch` on one global variable, let's say `qnumber.updated` and then update `$scope.qnumbers` with data passed by your C# code once the watch gets triggered.

Note that you will have to manually trigger a digest process after you change the global variable outside of angular.

Example:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Main', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch(function() {
      return window.qnumbers;
    }, function(data) {
      $scope.qnumbers = window.qnumbers || 'default';
    });
  });
```

You can execute the following command to fire this watch.

```
window.qnumbers = [1,2,3];
angular.element(document.getElementById('ctrl')).scope().$apply();
// ctrl is the id of you controller container
```

Check out this link as an example, and try to execute the command above in the console. You can do the same within your `EvaluateScriptAsync` method
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGzXKv

Comment: From angular js documentation $scope.$watch service helps you to run some code when some value attached to the $scope has changed. But how do we change the value in the first place? I need to know how do we update the data. That's why I ask how do we put the data into MainController?

Comment: You can watch to a global variable. Just remember to manually apply digest after you changed the value outside angular. See updated.

Comment: May I know how do we get window.qnumbers?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. `window` is a build-in variable, you can access it via cefsharp just like your `Random` function. By executing `window.qnumbers = [1,2,3]` in your EvaluateScriptAsync method you are changing the value pf this global variable.

Comment: This is the same reason you can invoke your `Random` function, it's a short for `window.Random`.

Comment: You mean I write like this in C#? window.qnumbers = [1,2,3]; EvaluateScriptAsync(window.qnumbers); Using this way I pass the data from c# to html?

Comment: No. I mean something like. `var command = "window.qnumbers=[1,2,3]; angular.element......."; EvaluateScriptAsync(command);`

Answer (score 0):

`$scope` is completely private and cannot be directly accessed from outside the `MainController` code.  To get data into the `$scope` you have to initiate the request from *inside* the `$scope` like with `$http.get`.  You can use `ng-init` to provide values from the server to an angular script at the pages initial load time, but after that you need to work from inside the scope.

**bind to a function**

You could invert this by binding to a function which itself requests the new data.  To do this "properly"<sup>1</sup> you would want to create a service which gets the qnumbers and inject that service to your controller.  I'm providing a example here of how to do without the service.  Your HTML would be

```
            <div class="reg" ng-repeat="qnumber in getQnumbers()">
               div class="u1">{{qnumber.counter}}</div>
               <div class="u2">{{qnumber.number}}</div>
            </div>
```

and your angular would be

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.getQnumbers = function() {
        return window.cefSharpQnumbers;
    };
}]);
```

Then in your `EvaluateScriptAsync` script you would store the result to `window.cefSharpQnumbers`.

**$watch**

Similar to the above approach, but your angular code uses a normal binding and you create a `$watch` in the scope to update your scope when non scope items change.  The `$watch` code really belongs in either a service or a directive (as discussed above).

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.$watch("window.cefSharpQnumbers", function(newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.qnumbers = window.cefSharpQnumbers;
    });
}]);
```

Warning: This approach might cause your screen to "jump" a little bit when the qnumbers are updated.

Original **ng-init example**

Use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).  Any values you include in the init code will be set as a property on your scope.

Your code would be along these lines

```
<div ng-controller="MainController"
     ng-init="{
         myVar1: @Model.Var1,
         myStringVar: '@Model.StringVar'
     }"
>
```

That would give you access to `$scope.myVar1` and `$scope.myStringVar` in your controller.  Note that `ng-init` runs *after* your controller function is called so you cannot use the values directly in the controller function.

<sup>1</sup> Putting a direct connection between the controller and the `window` like this breaks angular's modularization.  Using a service would bring that moudualrization back.  That makes the code easier to manage and to test.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I just want to know how do we put data into the MainController (beside hardcode it)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems like I always have to request the data from the html page. But I want my C# app to send the data whenever the data is available instead of asking my html always requesting. Is there a way to do this? I can do it if I'm not using angular js. Read my comment on my question at top. But now I want to try using angular js to do it.

Comment: @Coolguy Binding to the `getQnumbers` function I suggested will have the efect of sending it from your C#.  When you run your `EvaluateScriptAsync` it will update the value of `window.cefSharpQnumbers` which will in turn "update" the angular $scope.  Now that I think of it more, it's probably more efficient to do this with a $watch, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I'm not quite understand the window.cefSharpQnumbers. Can you explain it? I use EvaluateScriptAsync to call a function from html. How can it update window.cefSharpQnumbers?

Comment: @Coolguy, You would write the code to change the value of `window.cefSharpQnumbers` inside the function you call from `EvaluateScriptAsync`.  Like `var script = string.Format("window.cefSharpQnumbers = [{0}, {1}]");", data1, data2);`.